# Can I use vermicomposting leachate to moisturize my worm bin?

Tags: compost, worms, vermicomposting

I have a two container vermicomposting system with the bottom container having a tap to drain the leachate. I think I am maintaining my worm bin correctly as material feels damp but I cannot wring any water out of it. I spray some water on it very rarely if the top portion feels very dry.  My worms do look happy - at least they are consuming the expected amount of food.

I do get a small amount of leachate (maybe quarter of an inch in depth) in the bottom bin. Sometimes I also see a few worms in the bottom bin, but I do know that they keep moving upwards when they need to.  I am wondering if I can just pour the leachate back into the worm bin?  I think the water should have bacteria and other stuff that might help decomposition a little more.

Comment: [This article](https://www.gardenmyths.com/vermicompost-leachate-will-it-harm-plants/) offers a scientific look into the issue of using diluted leachate as fertilizer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If there is just a little water in the bottom, then the next time you moisten your worm bin you should be able to just pour it back over the top.

[Wikipedia says](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vermicompost):

> The dark brown waste liquid, or leachate, that drains into the bottom of some vermicomposting systems as water-rich foods break down, is best applied back to the bin when added moisture is needed due to the possibility of phytotoxin content and organic acids that may be toxic to plants

However, that having been said, I have heard many folks do use the leachate as a liquid organic fertilizer and don't have problems with it.

Answer (score 1):

compost leachate poses no real environmental harm, applying it directly to your lawn or plants is fine. Top off your compost bin with fresh water.